# Table view data pass with arrays

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, tableview

Friends, I want to make table views data pass with each other with the array.

if we click on the category food on the first table view, it should show the detail option of bar restaurant on the second table view on unique rows, I don't know how to pass data between, Please help, I can provide the code if you want and can send screen shots if needed.

[image: first table view]
[image: second table view]

I need the view to be like this please help as fast as possible.

```
#import "categoryViewController.h"

@interface categoryViewController ()<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
{
NSArray *tableData,*thumbNails;
}
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *categoryTable;
@property (weak,nonatomic) NSArray *tabledata;
@end

@implementation categoryViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    tableData = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Food and Drinks",@"Shopping",@"Housing",@"Transportation",@"Vehicle",@"Life and Entertainment",@"Communication & PC",@"Financial Expenses",@"Investment",@"Income",@"Others",nil];

//thumbnails=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Food and Drinks.png"@"Shopping.png",@"Shopping.png",@"Shopping.png",@"Shopping.png",@"Shopping.png",@"Shopping.png",@"Shopping.png",@"Shopping.png",@"Shopping.png",@"Shopping.png", nil];

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:  (NSInteger)section
{
return tableData.count;
}

 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{   //Updated method to go to the next View.
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    //outdated method.
  //  UITableViewCell *cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    // work on ittttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt.

    return cell;
    }
    /*
    -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
NSIndexPath *index = [self.categoryTable indexPathForSelectedRow];
subcategoryViewController *scVC = [segue destinationViewController];
}
*/
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)backBtn:(id)sender{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

@end

Comment: add some code and image what you want?

Comment: I've added the images and I'll send you the code as well.

Comment: in didselectrowatindexpath method store particular index value in next vc string variable

Comment: add code in your quetion

Comment: dude I m new to this place could you be more specific

Comment: if possible than send me your project

Comment: @IOS_DEV okay where should i send any email address you have

Comment: upload in github/drive and give me link or

Comment: @IOS_DEV just give me aa moment i'll send you the project

Comment: @IOS_DEV https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx-XmgesCzEuOTlLNFhHNkd5aDA

Comment: Any solutions @IOS_DEV

Comment: you can pass your data by using indexpath.row in didselectatindexpath to another table.

Comment: @KrishSolanki bro could you give me an example so that i can understand what you are talking about

Comment: @John Sahil tommorrow i will check your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@john there is two way to pass data like the way you want ,1 . either you separately create the variable on to navigate contraoller and give value them  in segue method 2. or you can pass your data by using the key value
and if you want more detail than share ur screen shot how you want to manage your data.